# Is Postgres Autovacuum causing a read query to stuck at IOWait wait event?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance, autovacuum, iowait

I have encountered several occasions where my read query is stuck for hours and when checked on `pg_stat_activity` it has `wait_event_type` of `IOWait`. It also happens that every time this happens, there is an active autovacuum running on that table. The table is a partitioned table using pg_partman and I am using Postgres 11.

Simplified version of query

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings
WHERE user_id=? AND user_type=?
```

There is an index for the query, something like

```
CREATE index_user_id_user_type ON bookings(user_id, user_type)
```

I noticed that there is an optimization on Postgres 14 with regards to autovacuum on partitioned table (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html) which made me more suspicious that autovacuum is indeed the reason for this stuck/hang query with IOWait

> Autovacuum now analyzes partitioned tables (Yuzuko Hosoya, Álvaro Herrera)
>
> Insert, update, and delete tuple counts from partitions are now propagated to their parent tables so autovacuum knows when to process them.

Could this be caused by autovacuum?

- If yes, why? Is there a way to avoid this?
- If no, what could be the reason?

**Edit(1)** Added table schema & explain plan

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE public.bookings (
   order_number text not null,
   event_timestamp with time zone not null,
   customer_id text not null,
   driver_id text,
   ...
) PARTITION BY RANGE (event_timestamp);
```

Explain plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/y3YH

Comment: @jjanes added to the question description

Comment: Is this some cloud provider with throttled/burstable IO capacity?  Once you have exhausted your IO credit balance, performance will be horrible.

Comment: The plan you show can not belong to the query you show.  If you query finishes, then you should do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Turn on `track_io_timing` first, if you can.

Comment: "wait_event_type" is too general.  Can you get the specific "wait_event"?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The wait event proves that you are waiting for I/O. `VACUUM` does a lot of I/O. These two facts together strongly point in the direction of an overloaded I/O system.

If on Linux, you can verify that by watching the I/O wait percentage of the CPU time in `vmstat 1`: if the value is consistently over 10, you have a proof.

Either improve the I/O capacity or slow down autovacuum by lowering `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit`. I recommend the first, because if autovacuum is too slow, you can end up with even worse problems.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Yeah we did monitor the I/O of the linux machine and indeed there was a spike during the period. However it seemed that Autovacuum has finished in some time, yet the query was still stuck at I/O wait. In the `pg_stat_activity` I saw `autovacuum launcher` has a wait type of `Activity` which I suppose is waiting for trigger. Do you have any clue as to why even though Autovacuum has finished, it left the read query stuck for I/O wait for hours? My assumption was I/O resources should recover and the read query should get unblocked after vacuum finished.

Comment: The autovacuum launcher certainly is innocent. Look for other things consuming I/O, perhaps outside PostgreSQL.